# How to get an item from a second df if there is a match between them

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Probably this question has already an answer, but I could not succeed to find any.

I want to get items from a second data-frame to be appended to a new column in the first dataframe if there a match between both dataframe

Here I am showing some sample data quite similar to the case I am confronting.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(3).repeat(3)
b = np.tile(np.arange(3),3)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':a, 'b':b})

    a   b
0   0   0
1   0   1
2   0   2
3   1   0
4   1   1
5   1   2
6   2   0
7   2   1
8   2   2

a2 = np.arange(1, 4).repeat(3)
b2 = np.tile(np.arange(3),3)
c = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=a2.size)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a2':a2, 'b2':b2, 'c':c})


  a2    b2  c
0   1   0   3
1   1   1   1
2   1   2   9
3   2   0   5
4   2   1   8
5   2   2   4
6   3   0   1
7   3   1   6
8   3   2   1
```

The desired output should be like

```
    a   b  c
0   0   0 nan
1   0   1 nan
2   0   2 nan
3   1   0 3
4   1   1 1
5   1   2 9
6   2   0 5
7   2   1 8
8   2   2 4
```

Unfortunately, I could not come up with anyway to solve it.

Comment: left join will work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join and rename columns names:

```
df = df1.merge(df2.rename(columns={'a2':'a', 'b2':'b'}), on=['a','b'], how='left')
print (df)
   a  b    c
0  0  0  NaN
1  0  1  NaN
2  0  2  NaN
3  1  0  3.0
4  1  1  5.0
5  1  2  0.0
6  2  0  2.0
7  2  1  6.0
8  2  2  2.0
```